# Spring Reactor Thread Model

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Newbie alert to Spring Webflux (v 2.0.1.RELEASE).

I'd like to use Spring Webflux for a back end (Webless) application for processing a large amount of data from a JMS listener.

My understanding is Spring Webflux provides an ]non-blocking/async concurrency model. However, I got a basic question for which I need some help. As a disclaimer, this whole concept of reactive programming is very new to me and I'm still in the process of this paradigm shift.

Consider this code:

```
Mono.just("ONE")
.map(item -> func(" A " + item))
.map(item -> func(" B " + item))
.map(item -> func(" C " + item))
.subscribe(System.out::println);

Mono.just("TWO")
.map(item -> func(" A " + item))
.map(item -> func(" B " + item))
.map(item -> func(" C " + item))
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I understand from the docs that nothing happens to the event processing chain until a "subscribe" function is called upon.

But internally, does the spring use (if it wishes) use separate threads asynchronously for every function inside the "map" function? If spring uses a "single" thread for these chains, then what's the real purpose here? Isn't it a blocking and single threaded model based on a different syntax?

I observe that the code always behaves sequentially and with the same thread. What's the threading model of spring webflux?

Answer (score 6):

Reactive programming is a programming paradigm and as such it doesn't make any assumptions about the technical implementation.

[The reactive manifesto](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) describes reactive systems and brings asynchronous communication and backpressure on the table. Other than that it also makes no assumptions about technical details.

Spring Reactor, the foundation of Webflux, is a library that allows you to easily build reactive systems and follow the reactive programming paradigm.

The thread that is used by a stream depends on the publisher. The default is to use the current thread. Without any intervention, the stream cannot be asynchronous if a publisher is synchronous. And the stream is blocking if a publisher blocks. But take the following example:

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
    .take(2)
    .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```

`Flux.interval` publishes on another thread and so the chain runs asynchronously in another thread.

Let's look at another example:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newElastic("foo");

Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.just(1, 2)
    .subscribeOn(scheduler);

flux.subscribe(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
flux.subscribe(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```

You will notice that each subscriber runs on its own thread (from the same thread pool though). The `publishOn` operator is similar.

If you subscribe to a publisher you can use the same programming paradigm regardless of whether it's synchronous or asynchronous. And you can always introduce asynchronous behavior by adding a `subscribeOn` or `publishOn` operator.

Answer (score 2):

**TL; DR:**

1. It's a Project Reactor thing, Spring-Webflux doesn't decide what operation runs on which thread.
2. Project Reactor makes it easier to tell where you're crossing the thread boundaries. Also, there's no (explicit) synchronization going on; making it harder to introduce concurrency problems.

No, it isn't a single threaded model with a different syntax. Project Reactor tries as much as possible to use your main thread to avoid context-switches. In addition, it provides special operators which lets you specify the threads that previous operations run on.

For instance, this modified example would run on different threads; as `subscribeOn` operator defines which thread pool the whole chain runs on:

```
Mono.just("ONE")
    .map(item -> func(" A " + item))
    .map(item -> func(" B " + item))
    .map(item -> func(" C " + item))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .subscribe(item -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + item);
    });

Mono.just("TWO")
    .map(item -> func(" A " + item))
    .map(item -> func(" B " + item))
    .map(item -> func(" C " + item))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .subscribe(item -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + item);
    });
```

In this case, both operations execute on an `elastic-x` thread; not blocking the main thread. The order of the operations might vary with each run.